# adding a second table to the web api in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a simple web api project using Entity Framework on AP.Net 2013. It performs basic CRUD. The project is connected to a SQL Server database with 2 tables - Students and Subjects. These two tables are connected with the Roll number being a PK in Students and FK in Subjects.

The project works fine when I am accessing only the Students. It gives me a `NotSupportedException` when I add the code to handle the subjects also.

I am running this app in the Fiddler.

My code is as below:

```
private StudentDBEntities db = new StudentDBEntities();

// GET: api/Student
public IList<SubjectDetailsDto> GetStudents()
{
    return db.Students.Select(s => new SubjectDetailsDto
    {
        Roll_Number = s.Roll_Number,
        FirstName = s.FirstName,
        LastName = s.LastName,
        Class = s.Class,
        Gender = s.Gender,
        subjects = s.subjects.ToList()
    }).ToList();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the exception is occurring?

**EDIT:** SubjectDetailsDto.cs

```
public class SubjectDetailsDto
{
    public int Roll_Number { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Class { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> subjects { get; set; }
}
```

I have added a snapshot of the exception:
[image]

**EDIT**

Student.cs

```
    public partial class Student
    {
      public int Roll_Number { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public int Class { get; set; }
      public string Gender { get; set; }

      public ICollection<Subject> subjects { get; set; }
   }
```

Subject.cs

```
public partial class Subject
{
    public int Roll_Number { get; set; }
    public int English { get; set; }
    public int Mathematics { get; set; }
    public int Science { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Total { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public Student student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is this line generate error ?  subjects = s.subjects.ToList()

Comment: The entire return statement seems to be a problem

Comment: yaa but first identify the line of return statement

Comment: cam you please post class file you used to store values

Comment: I did not seed the database. It is not a localDB. I connected to an external SQL server with the data.

Comment: i mean class of SubjectDetailsDto

Comment: Also it would be helpful to have the full exception detail rather than just the type

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer

Comment: I am not using Javascript or any flavor of it. I am also not using HTML to display. I am getting the output in Fiddler in JSON format

Comment: Can you also post your `Student` and `Subject` classes, along with any other relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is the fact that Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate `Enumerable.ToList()` into SQL code that will load the data.
The culprit line is this one:

```
subjects = s.subjects.ToList()
```

In order to avoid this you could join the tables or load the data in two separate requests:

```
var students = db.Students.Select(s => {}).ToList();
var studentIds = students.Select(s=>s.Id).ToArray();
var subjects = db.Subjects.Where(s=>studentIds.Contains(s.StudentId))
    .ToArray()
    .GroupBy(s=>s.StudentId)
    .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.ToList());
//Populate subjects for each student
students.ForEach(s=>
{
    s.subjects = subjects.ContainsKey(s.Id)?subjects[s.Id]:new List<Subject>();
});
```

Comment: @PallaviPrasad, can you post the line where it throws?

Comment: I used your code. The error comes in the first line. `var students = db.Students.Select(s => new SubjectDetailsDto {}).Tolist();`