# Using a function defined as a Linq.Expression in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I found this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer/16041979) accepted answer very informative to use Expressions with Linq to Entities. I can't figure out the VB.NET syntax, however.

Given something like (this part being in C# is fine)

```
public class MyCSClass 
{
    public static Expression<Func<unit, bool>> IsSomeStatus()
    {
        return u => u.IDStatus == (int)Enums.UnitStatus.SomeStatus;
    }
}
```

How do I put this expression in VB.NET like I would in C# like:

```
db.units.Any(MyCSClass.IsSomeStatus());
```

VB.NET doesn't recognize the type when I do either:

```
db.units.Where(MyCSClass.IsSomeStatus())
```

> (Value of type 'Expression(Of Func(Of unit, Boolean))' cannot be
>   converted to 'Func(Of unit, Boolean)')

or

```
db.units.Where(Function(u) MyCSClass.IsSomeStatus())
```

> (Value of type 'Expression(Of Func(Of unit, Boolean))' cannot be
>   converted to 'Boolean')

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this - are you entierly sure that your db.units is actually an *IQueryable* and not a regular *IEnumerable*; Related fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2K04x with more or less equivalent VB code

Comment: If you ever need to transform Expression into its delegate form just call .Compile()