# Display data from SQL View into a ListView on an ASP.net page | Error: NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-view, notsupportedexception

**Goal**: Display data from SQL View into a ListView on an asp.net page
There is a new database with a new view and I need to point it to that

**ERROR**:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
Inner Exception
NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Alternate_ID' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'When the DataBoundControl has paging enabled, either the SelectMethod should return an IQueryable or should have all these mandatory parameters : int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount'

**Tried:**
I've looked through the tutorials on listview, documentation, itemtype, data binding, etc. One of the SO I found was : [The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer)
Ive looked into the models, views, checked spelling, designer files, pocos, etc.

**CODE:**

*default.aspx*:

```
 <asp:ListView id="lstClaims" runat="server" ItemType="Placeholder.Data.vx_EligibilitySearch" SelectMethod="lstMembers_GetData" OnItemCommand="lstMembers_ItemCommand" 
        ItemPlaceholderID="litPlaceHolder">
 <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th><asp:LinkButton id="Sort_Claim_Number" runat="server" CommandArgument="Group_Description" CommandName="Sort">Group</asp:LinkButton></th>
                            <th><asp:LinkButton id="Sort_Claim_Status" runat="server" CommandArgument="Group_ID" CommandName="Sort">Group ID</asp:LinkButton></th>
                            <th><asp:LinkButton id="Sort_Plan" runat="server" CommandArgument="Alternate_ID" CommandName="Sort">Member ID</asp:LinkButton></th>

</thead>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </table>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>



 <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Item.Group_Description %></td>
                <td><%# Item.Group_ID %></td>
                <td><%# Item.Alternate_ID %></td>

  </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Note: protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView lstClaims; is in default.aspx.designer.cs

This points to [ lstClaims.DataBind(); ] :

```
  if (memberIDIsValid || memberIsValid)
            {
                ShouldSearch = true;
                lstClaims.DataBind();
            }
```

This is in the method: 
lnkSearch_Click, which is called from the aspx page here (When clicking the Search button):

```
<p><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch" runat="server" OnClick="lnkSearch_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search Members</asp:LinkButton></p>
```

Method to get Data:

```
public IQueryable<vx_EligibilitySearch> lstMembers_GetData()
        {
            litNumSearchResults.Text = "";

            // IQueryable<Member> members = null;
            IQueryable<vx_EligibilitySearch> members = null;


            try
            {
                if (!ShouldSearch)
                    return members;

                panelSearchForm.Visible = false;
                lnkButtonBackToSearch.Visible = true;

                members = GetDataFromQuery();


public IQueryable<vx_EligibilitySearch> GetDataFromQuery()  
        {
            // IQueryable<Member> members = null;
            IQueryable<vx_EligibilitySearch> members = null;



            try
            {
                // members = somedb.Members.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(); //.OrderBy(a => a.Claim_Number)
                members = somedb.vx_EligibilitySearch.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(); //.OrderBy(a => a.Claim_Number)


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_MemberID))
                    // members = members.Where(m => m.Subscriber_ID == Search_MemberID).AsQueryable();
                    members = members.Where(m => m.Alternate_ID == Search_MemberID).AsQueryable();
```

In partial class vx_EligibilitySearch I have:

```
public string Alternate_ID { get; set; }
```

More:

```
namespace Placeholder.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class vx_EligibilitySearch
    {
        public string Subscriber_ID { get; set; }


        public string Group_Description { get; set; }
        public string Group_ID { get; set; }
        public string Alternate_ID { get; set; }
        public string Member_Name { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Birth_Date { get; set; }
```

DbContext :

```
members = somedb.vx_EligibilitySearch.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(); //.OrderBy(a => a.Claim_Number)
```

Going to Definition of somedb takes me to BasePage.cs with:

```
protected VBADemoEntities somedb = new VBADemoEntities();
```

When I go to definition of VBADemoEntities:

```
namespace Placeholder.Data

public partial class VBADemoEntities : DbContext
    {
        public VBADemoEntities()
            : base("name=VBADemoEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Auth> Auths { get; set; }
        ...........
        public virtual DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<vx_EligibilitySearch> vx_EligibilitySearch { get; set; }
```

Comment: `somedb.vx_EligibilitySearch` what is `vx_EligibilitySearch` mapping to in the backend database? Is it some view?

Comment: Yes there is a View in SQL Server with that name

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework core? Ensure your view returns Alternate_ID column. Share code related to how SQL View is mapped to `vx_EligibilitySearch` class?

Comment: I have EntityFramework in the References. I added some more of the vx_EligibilitySearch.cs at the bottom. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Does `vx_EligibilitySearch` returns `Alternate_ID` column when you select from this view? Also, can you share your DbContext class `somedb` code?

Comment: When I run that View in SQL Server it returns data. I just added DbContext to the post

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do object comparison inside the Entity Framework query because EF need to convert your LINQ statements  to SQL Queries in order to perform any actions(query).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. How would you not be able to read from a View? Why would they exist if they cant be used. Isn't this saying the opposite ? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1990/how-to-use-sql-server-views-with-the-entity-framework/