# EF6 Linq query for joining tables with view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

The current error code presents me with an issue I can't decipher, Line 67:

> The specified type member 'ClinicalAssetID' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I am trying to bring into the `DashBoard` view two models that have relational data which is the `ClinicalAssetID` using `LINQ` and `viewmodel`

Not sure if my code is going the right way about it ?

**Controller:**

```
namespace Assets.Areas.Clinical.Controllers
{
    public class ClinicalAssetsController : Controller
    {
        private ClinicalContext db = new ClinicalContext();
        [Authorize]
        // GET: Clinical/ClinicalAssets
        public async Task<ActionResult> DashBoard(string sortOrder, string currentFilter,string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var clinicalAssets = (from s in db.ClinicalAssets
                                  join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID


                                 select new ClinicalASSPATVM
                                 {
                                     InspectionDocumnets = cp.InspectionDocumnets,
                                 });


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                clinicalAssets = clinicalAssets.Where(s => s.SerialNo.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.PoNo.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    clinicalAssets = clinicalAssets.OrderByDescending(s => s.PoNo);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    clinicalAssets = clinicalAssets.OrderBy(s => s.PurchaseDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    clinicalAssets = clinicalAssets.OrderBy(s => s.ClinicalAssetID);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(await clinicalAssets.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

**ClinicalASSPATVM:**

```
namespace Assets.Areas.Clinical.Models
{
    public class ClinicalASSPATVM
    {
        public int ClinicalAssetID { get; set; }
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public string PoNo { get; set; }
        public float? Costing { get; set; }
        public string InspectionDocumnets { get; set; }

        public virtual Model ModelName { get; set; }
        public virtual BudgetCode Code { get; set; }
        public virtual Product ProductName { get; set; }
        public virtual AssetType AssetTypeName { get; set; }
        public virtual Manufacturer ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        public virtual Staff StaffName { get; set; }
        public virtual Team TeamName { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier SupplierName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**ClinicalAsset:**

```
namespace Assets.Areas.Clinical.Models
{
    public class ClinicalAsset
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClinicalAssetID { get; set; }
        public int AssetTypeID { get; set; }
        public int? ProductID { get; set; }
        public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }
        public int? ModelID{ get; set; }
        public int? SupplierID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string PoNo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
        public float? Costing { get; set; }
        public int? TeamID { get; set; }
        public int? BudgetCodeID { get; set; }
        public int? StaffID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]


        public virtual Model ModelName { get; set; }
        public virtual BudgetCode Code { get; set; }
        public virtual Product ProductName { get; set; }
        public virtual AssetType AssetTypeName { get; set; }
        public virtual Manufacturer ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        public virtual Staff StaffName { get; set; }
        public virtual Team TeamName { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier SupplierName { get; set; }
        public List<ClinicalPAT> ClinicalPATs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ClinicalPAT:**

```
namespace Assets.Areas.Clinical.Models
{
    public class ClinicalPAT
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClinicalPATID { get; set; }
        public int ClinicalAssetID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WarrantyEndDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:ddd/MMMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? InspectionDate { get; set; }
        public int? InspectionOutcomeID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string InspectionDocumnets { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:ddd/MMMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? InspectionDueDate { get; set; }

        public virtual InspectionOutcome InspectionOutcomeResult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
from s in db.ClinicalAssets
join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID
select new ClinicalASSPATVM
{
    InspectionDocumnets = cp.InspectionDocumnets,
}
```

To

```
from s in db.ClinicalAssets
join cp in db.ClinicalPATs on s.ClinicalAssetID equals cp.ClinicalAssetID
select new ClinicalASSPATVM
{
    ClinicalAssetID = cp.ClinicalAssetID,
    InspectionDocumnets = cp.InspectionDocumnets
}
```

Link: [The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer)