# C# order List of Parent objects by Child's property via Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, iqueryable

I have a method that orders a queryable by a property via reflection, like so:

```cs
   public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty, bool desc)
   {
       string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
       var parts = orderByProperty.Split('.');
       var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "p");
       Expression body = parameter;
       if (parts.Length > 1)
       {
           for (var i = 0; i < parts.Length - 1; i++)
           {
               body = Expression.Property(body, parts[i]);
           }
       }
       var property = body.Type.GetProperty(parts.LastOrDefault())
       body = Expression.Property(body, property.Name);
       var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
       resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, 
                                       new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), property.PropertyType },
                                       source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
       return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
   }
```

And it works if I use it for the object's properties or its children's properties, but it doesn't work when a child property is a List.

```cs
    // Success
    db.Users.OrderBy("Name", true)
    db.Users.OrderBy("CurrentAddress.City.Name", false)

    // Fail
    db.Users.OrderBy("PhoneLines.RenewalDate", true)
```

My model is like so:

```cs
    public class User {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address CurrentAddress{ get; set; }
        public List<Phone> PhoneLines { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am trying to do something like this work:

```cs
    db.Users.OrderByDescending(x => 
        x.PhoneLines
          .OrderByDescending(y => y.RenewalDate)
          .Select(y => y.RenewalDate).FirstOrDefault()
    );
```

Right now I am only interested in making this work for first level List children, that is, I am not concerned about a cascading list scenario, just one child in the chain is a list.

So far my attempts have failed. I am checking if the last property is a collection and if so i tried creating a lambda for the list and another lambda for the class' element target order property.

```cs
if (body.Type.Namespace.Equals("System.Collections.Generic"))
{
 var mainType = body.Type.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
 var parameterInner = Expression.Parameter(mainType, "x");
 var mainProperty = Expression.Property(parameterInner, property.Name);
 var orderByExpressionInner = Expression.Lambda(mainProperty, parameterInner);
 var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);

 var selM = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
             .Where(x => x.Name == command)
             .First().MakeGenericMethod(mainType, property.PropertyType);

 var resultExpressionOuter = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
                            command, new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), body.Type },
                            source.Expression, 
                            Expression.Call(null, selM, parameterInner, orderByExpressionInner
                        ));
}
```

My knowledge with reflection is limited, is it possible to achieve this via reflection?

Comment: `So far my attempts have failed` can you elaborate on that? What happens and what do you expect instead?

Comment: The latest attempt results in the following exception: 
`Expression of type 'Phone' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Phone]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'1[Phone] OrderBy[Phone,System.DateTime](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Phone], System.Func'2[Phone,System.DateTime])'`

I expect it to build an expression successfully orders an EF dataset with `source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression)`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to place a new property on your parent class and make this responsible for returning the value which you require.  Such as this;

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address CurrentAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> PhoneLines { get; set; }

    private DateTime _dummyValue;
    public DateTime GetRenewalDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.PhoneLines == null || this.PhoneLines.Count == 0)
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            else
            {
                return this.PhoneLines.OrderByDescending(y => y.RenewalDate).Select(y => y.RenewalDate).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        set
        {
             _dummyValue = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Make sure you have default handling in case your list is empty or null, here I return MinValue of DateTime.

Edit:
To get around the other issue you have put in the comments

> The specified type member 'GetRenewalDate' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

You could try adding a dummy set, this might also work as a workaround (but is not elegant).
I have edited the code above to show this

Comment: That is a clever solution, but it it's throwing `'The specified type member 'GetRenewalDate' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'`

Comment: Oh, ok!  A "dirty" solution is to convert to a list.  See the 2nd answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer

Comment: @BrunoDiGiuseppe I have updated the solution to use a dummy set, this sometimes works but is very dirty!