# Entity Framework NotMapped Join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, data-annotations

I have a model that links to a DB table with a few **non-mapped fields** that I need to populate via a join in EF.

Here is my current attempt at this which returns the following error:

> The specified type member db_current_value is not supported in LINQ
> to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
> properties are supported.

```
Model = MainTable
composite_mapped_id1
composite_mapped_id2
general_mapped_label
mapped_calucluation
not_mapped_property_current //not_mapped
not_mapped_property_previous //not_mapped


var queryCurrent = from t in _context.MainTable
                               where t.Data_Period == "04/01/2021"
                               select
                               new //Anonymous
                               {
                                   //CASE STATEMENTS HERE
                                   composite_id1 = t.composite_mapped_id1,
                                   composite_id2 = t.composite_mapped_id2,
                                   general_label = t.general_mapped_label,
                                   not_mapped_property_current = t.mapped_calucluation

                               };



            var queryPrevious = from t in _context.MainTable
                                where t.Data_Period == "01/01/2021"
                                select
                               new //Anonymous
                               {
                                   composite_id1 = t.composite_mapped_id1,
                                   composite_id2 = t.composite_mapped_id2,
                                   not_mapped_property_previous = t.mapped_calucluation

                               };



            var queryFinal = (from c in queryCurrent
                              from p in queryPrevious
                              where c.composite_id1 == p.composite_id1 && c.composite_id2 == p.composite_id2
                              select c).AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(x => new MainTable
                            {

                                general_label = t.general_mapped_label,
                                not_mapped_property_current = x.not_mapped_property_current,
                                not_mapped_property_previous =  c.not_mapped_property_previous //NOT SURE HOW TO REFERENCE THIS 


                            }).ToList();
```

Any suggestions on how to tweak this or perhaps a completely different approach?

UPDATE:
I Decided to go with a NonMapped ViewModel to support this. Not sure if it's ideal though:

```
var current = _context.MainTable.Where(c => c.Data_Period == "01/01/2021").ToList();
var previous = _context.MainTable.Where(p => p.Data_Period == "04/01/2021").ToList();
    
var queryFinal = (from c in current
                  from p in previous
                  where c.composite_id1 == p.composite_id1 && 
                  c.composite_id2 == p.composite_id2
                  select
                  new MainTable_Interface_Model
                  {
                        general_label = c.general_mapped_label,
                        property_current = c.mapped_calucluation,
                        property_previous = p.mapped_calucluation
    
                  }).ToList();
```

UPDATE #2
First UPDATE was too slow so for now I went with my comfort zone of SQL

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<MainTable_Interface_Model>(strSQL).ToList<MainTable_Interface_Model>();
```

Comment: How it even compiles? First anonymous type does not have `db_mapped_value_Calculations` property.

Comment: It might helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv, Its just a mockup, hoping I could get the question across

Comment: If you hide real query, I cannot help.

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv, I have updated the code

Comment: Your first UPDATE is correct.

Comment: It's very slow though. I suspect it's all the toList() calls. Any suggestions on how to improve its performance? The SQL approach is 20x faster...